# SSRS Percentage display

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm not at all skilled when it comes to SQL but I'm trying to
reflect some data to a percentage.
an example

```
Times Called on Enquiry |  ContractNumber | Enquiry  | Percentage to Display

          1                101            Claim         14.28%
          1                101           Complaint      85.71%
          2                101           Complaint      85.71%
          3                101           Complaint      85.71%
          4                101           Complaint      85.71%
          5                101           Complaint      85.71%
          6                101           Complaint      85.71%
```

So the formula to work out the percentage goes as follows
[total enquiries by contract number / maxrows(contractnumber)]

How would I achieve this? any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using and show desired results as well as sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.  I am assuming that you are using SQL Server.  And, that your goal is to get the percentage.  This would seem to be the ratio of "Enquiry" to the total for the "Contract Number".  If so, you can use window functions:

```
select e.*,
       (count(*) over (partition by ContractNumber, Enquiry) * 1.0 /
        count(*) over (partition by ContractNumber)
       ) as ratio
from enquiries e;
```

You can do what you want to format this as a percentage.  That would normally be done at the application layer.